# pod lib lint showing no such module error

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, cocoapods, podspec

I am creating a pod framework and in one of file of my project I have used a third party library `DataCompression`. I have a podspec file related to it, to which I run `pod lib lint` and I am getting this

```
-> MyPod (0.1.0)
    - WARN  | http: The URL (`~/Desktop/qwerty/`) doesn't use the encrypted HTTPS protocol. It is crucial for Pods to be transferred over a secure protocol to protect your users from man-in-the-middle attacks. This will be an error in future releases. Please update the URL to use https.
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using new build system
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Planning build
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Constructing build description
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  /Users/shubhambhiwaniwala/Desktop/qwerty/qwerty/Encryptor.swift:10:8: error: no such module 'DataCompression'

[!] MyPod did not pass validation, due to 2 errors.
You can use the `--no-clean` option to inspect any issue.
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: have you add DataCompression as a dependency framework in your podspec?

Comment: Thanx @AlexandrKolesnik for confirming. I didn't try it properly earlier.